# get output of an array and use it mysql query

Tags: php

I have the following php script, which selects and insert into the array all the user_ids I want to select.

```
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT `user_id` FROM users WHERE (surname LIKE '$name%' AND name LIKE '$surname%') OR (surname LIKE '$surname%' AND name LIKE '$name%') ");

    while($run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $user_id = $run['user_id']; 

        $check_friend_query = mysql_query("  SELECT friends_id from friends WHERE  (user_one='$session_user_id' AND user_two ='$user_id') OR (user_one='$user_id' AND user_two='$session_user_id')   ");

            if( mysql_num_rows($check_friend_query) == 1  ){    
                    $array[] = $user_id;
            }
    }
```

By using then the following script, I get the output of all user ids that I have in the array:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {

    echo "$value </br>";

}
```

In my case this ouput prints me 5 user ids : 32, 36, 37, 38, 39.

All I want is to use these values in the following sql query:

```
$sql = " SELECT `name`, `surname`, `email`, `user_id` FROM users WHERE ((surname LIKE '$name%' AND name LIKE '$surname%') OR (surname LIKE '$surname%' AND name LIKE '$name%')) AND `user_id`='$value'  ";
```

but if write it like above the query works only for one value, in my case for 39 and not for all. How can I make it work for all?

Comment: if every your user have an unique `user_id` you can select them only by doing `WHERE user_id = $value` which will be much simpler query, and may resolve your problem.

Comment: did it...but works only for value 39 (happens to be the last), not for all values

Comment: are you doing that query after or inside foreach loop with `$value`?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the sql statement inside the foreach loop, that way it will perform the command for each item in the array:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {

    echo "$value </br>";
    $sql = " SELECT `name`, `surname`, `email`, `user_id` FROM users WHERE ((surname LIKE '$name%' AND name LIKE '$surname%') OR (surname LIKE '$surname%' AND name LIKE '$name%')) AND `user_id`='$value'  ";

}
```

I'm not sure if you still want to output the values or not - if you don't need them, then take the echo command out.

Answer (score 0):

just put the query in loop

```
 foreach($array as $key => $value) {

     $sql = " SELECT `name`, `surname`, `email`, `user_id` FROM users WHERE ((surname LIKE  '$name%' AND name LIKE '$surname%') OR (surname LIKE '$surname%' AND name LIKE '$name%')) AND `user_id`='$value'  ";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me where you put $sql? If you put it inside loop, it'll get the last id's value is 39 when it fisnishes.